# Performing a for loop on a matrix instead of a data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data.table, sparse-matrix

I am performing a rather complicated linear regression that involves conditionally creating dummy variables in new columns with a for loop. So far I've been doing this in a couple of data frames, converting them to matrices, then converting those to sparse matrices, and then joining; however, I've reached my computer's limit. Sorry if this gets confusing - I've tried to simplify the process as much as I can.

**EDIT** - added all numeric examples to original question.

Here is the source data with all numeric values:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 4))
df$X1 <- c(5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6, 0)
df$X2 <- c(10001, 10001, 10001, 10003, 10003, 10003, 10002, 10002, 10002) 
df$X3 <- c(10002, 10002, 10002, 10001, 10001, 10001, 10003, 10003, 10003) 
df$X4 <- c(10001, 10001, 10001, 10003, 10003, 10003, 10002, 10002, 10002)
names(df) <- c("response", "group_1", "group_2", "exclude")
```

What that looks like:

```
  response group_1 group_2 exclude
1        5   10001   10002   10001
2        1   10001   10002   10001
3        2   10001   10002   10001
4        0   10003   10001   10003
5        4   10003   10001   10003
6        8   10003   10001   10003
7        7   10002   10003   10002
8        6   10002   10003   10002
9        0   10002   10003   10002
```

Source data (please see above edit):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 4))
df$X1 <- c(5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6, 0)
df$X2 <- c("blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green") 
df$X3 <- c("green", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow") 
df$X4 <- c("blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green")
names(df) <- c("response", "group_1", "group_2", "exclude")
```

This is a simplified version of what the data looks like:

```
  response group_1 group_2 exclude
1        5    blue   green    blue
2        1    blue   green    blue
3        2    blue   green    blue
4        0  yellow    blue  yellow
5        4  yellow    blue  yellow
6        8  yellow    blue  yellow
7        7   green  yellow   green
8        6   green  yellow   green
9        0   green  yellow   green
```

From the above data, I find the unique variables in "group_1" and "group_2" using the following function:

```
fun_names <- function(x) {
  row1 <- unique(x$group_1)
  row2 <- unique(x$group_2)
  mat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(row1) + length(row2), ncol = 1))
  mat[1] <- c(row1, row2)
  mat_unique <- data.frame(mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]), ])
  names(mat_unique) <- c("ID")

  return(mat_unique)
}
df_unique <- fun_names(df)
```

This returns the following data frame:

```
      ID
1   blue
2 yellow
3  green
```

Then for each color ("ID") I create a new column with a value of 1 if the color is in each row and the color does not match the "exclude" column value. The loop looks like this:

```
for(name in df_unique$ID) {
  df[paste(name)] <- 
    ifelse(df$group_1 == name & df$exclude != name | 
           df$group_2 == name & df$exclude != name, 1, 0)
}
```

Running this loop returns the final `data.frame` which looks like this:

**EDIT** 
Here is the numeric data final df:

```
  response group_1 group_2 exclude 10001 10003 10002
1        5   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
2        1   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
3        2   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
4        0   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
5        4   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
6        8   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
7        7   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
8        6   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
9        0   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
```

Here is the original data:

```
  response group_1 group_2 exclude blue yellow green
1        5    blue   green    blue    0      0     1
2        1    blue   green    blue    0      0     1
3        2    blue   green    blue    0      0     1
4        0  yellow    blue  yellow    1      0     0
5        4  yellow    blue  yellow    1      0     0
6        8  yellow    blue  yellow    1      0     0
7        7   green  yellow   green    0      1     0
8        6   green  yellow   green    0      1     0
9        0   green  yellow   green    0      1     0
```

So, my question: how do I perform this loop if the original data is a matrix (instead of a data frame)? Since the loop is modifying a data frame, I need to convert that data frame to a matrix in order to convert it to a sparse matrix - this `data.frame` to `data.matrix` conversion is too intensive for my machine.

I have converted everything in my code up until the above `for` loop to matrix notation, but I can't figure out how to print the new columns in this manner while modifying a matrix in R (instead of a data frame). Basically, I'm hoping someone could help me modify the `for` loop so it will work on a matrix. Does any one have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that the source data needs to retain it's grouping -
 `group_by(response, group_1, group_2, exclude)`. Also, the `df` object needs to start as a matrix to remove the `data.frame` to `data.matrix` conversion.

**EDIT2**
I did not mention this, but all data is indexed and converted into a numeric value before I run the entire process. So the `df` object in the example would actually be only numbers.

Comment: Converting to matrix will render all the numeric objects to character type. Do you want that? Why do you need the group info?

Comment: I have an additional step that itemizes and converts all data to numbers before I make it a matrix (which is saved in another data frame so I can convert it back after the regression is performed). I will specify that in the edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I maybe wrong, as I am not so sure of your use-case but  `factor` variables are one-hot-encoded to get `numeric` features and the `factor` variables are removed from data as the information is captured by the newly encoded variables.

Comment: If your data is all numeric (integer?), please provide an example with all-numeric data.

Comment: Added. I should have realized that when I originally submitted. Should I just make a new submission? This is getting long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sparse matrix for the dummy encoding:

```
m <- as.matrix(df)

groups <- unique(as.vector(m[, grep("group", colnames(m))]))
tmp <- lapply(groups, function(x, m) 
  which((m[, "group_1"] == x | m[, "group_2"] == x) & m[, "exclude"] != x),
       m = m)

j = rep(seq_along(tmp), lengths(tmp))
i = unlist(tmp)

library(Matrix)
dummies <- sparseMatrix(i, j, dims = c(nrow(m), length(groups)))
colnames(dummies) <- groups

M <- Matrix(as.matrix(df))
cbind(M, dummies)
#9 x 7 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#     response group_1 group_2 exclude 10001 10003 10002
#[1,]        5   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
#[2,]        1   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
#[3,]        2   10001   10002   10001     0     0     1
#[4,]        0   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
#[5,]        4   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
#[6,]        8   10003   10001   10003     1     0     0
#[7,]        7   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
#[8,]        6   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
#[9,]        0   10002   10003   10002     0     1     0
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Alright, so I think this will work! I'm trying to modify it to run on the intended data right now, but upon initial testing, I think I can make this work. Is there a reason you are making a new object for binding here - `M <- Matrix(as.matrix(df))`? When I bind in the dummies using the original `m` matrix - `cbind(m, dummies)` - it provides what looks like a spare matrix but is a `"dgCMatrix"` class. Do I need to create a new object for this to work?

Comment: I have been able to fully implement this in my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Is this too intense for your matrices?  It uses `dplyr` and `tidyr` to do away with for-loops altogether:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

m = df %>% 
    mutate(group = ifelse(group_1 == exclude, group_2, group_1), ones = 1) %>%
    select(response, group, ones) %>%
    spread(key = group, value = ones, fill = 0) %>%
    as.matrix
```

Comment: After trying this out, I realized that I didn't specify that I need to retain the grouping of the original data and the order - `group_by(response, group_1, and group_2, exclude)`. I also need to retain the original data... which is why I'm using a loop. Also, I think the as.matrix at the end may end up being just as memory intensive? I may be mis-interpreting though.

Comment: You can replace the `as.matrix` with a `merge(df, by = "response")` and get back something like the final dataframe in your question?  I'm not following why you need to convert to a matrix.  I may have gone a bit off-topic, but what is your end-goal?

Comment: No worries. Okay, so my end goal is two sparse matrixes that are 3 million rows x 1400 columns that I `rbind` into one big sparse matrix. Currently, I've been making each as a data.frame and then converting to sparse matrix afterwards (cleaning up my memory in between). However, I have more data that I need to include and I can't because of memory limitations (ultimate goal is a sparse matrix that is ~7 million rows x ~4000 columns). So, I was hoping I could perform exactly what I was doing but start with a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame` and update the code to work with a `matrix`.

Comment: I would suggest adding the `data.table` tag to your question (you can probably get rid of `loops` tag to make room for it).  This sounds like a problem involving `data.table` library, which is getting beyond my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

So I am starting with a matrix like this:

```
m <- matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 4)
m[,1]<- c(5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6, 0)
m[,2] <- c("blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green") 
m[,3] <- c("green", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow") 
m[,4] <- c("blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green", "green", "green")
colnames(m) <- c("response", "group_1", "group_2", "exclude")

>m
 #    response group_1  group_2  exclude 
 #[1,] "5"      "blue"   "green"  "blue"  
 #[2,] "1"      "blue"   "green"  "blue"  
 #[3,] "2"      "blue"   "green"  "blue"  
 #[4,] "0"      "yellow" "blue"   "yellow"
 #[5,] "4"      "yellow" "blue"   "yellow"
 #[6,] "8"      "yellow" "blue"   "yellow"
 #[7,] "7"      "green"  "yellow" "green" 
 #[8,] "6"      "green"  "yellow" "green" 
 #[9,] "0"      "green"  "yellow" "green"
```

Using the package **dummies'** `dummy()` function:

```
one_hot_encoded_vars = dummy(x="group_2", data = m))
>one_hot_encoded_vars
 #        group_2blue group_2green group_2yellow
 #[1,]           0            1             0
 #[2,]           0            1             0
 #[3,]           0            1             0
 #[4,]           1            0             0
 #[5,]           1            0             0
 #[6,]           1            0             0
 #[7,]           0            0             1
 #[8,]           0            0             1
 #[9,]           0            0             1
```

To create a numeric matrix with all variables included:

```
finalmatrix = cbind(as.numeric(m[,'response']),dummy(x = 'group_1',data = m),
    dummy(x = 'group_2',data = m),dummy(x = 'exclude',data=m))

>finalmatrix
#             group_1blue group_1green group_1yellow group_2blue group_2green group_2yellow excludeblue excludegreen
 #[1,] 5           1            0             0           0            1             0           1            0
 #[2,] 1           1            0             0           0            1             0           1            0
 #[3,] 2           1            0             0           0            1             0           1            0
 #[4,] 0           0            0             1           1            0             0           0            0
 #[5,] 4           0            0             1           1            0             0           0            0
 #[6,] 8           0            0             1           1            0             0           0            0
 #[7,] 7           0            1             0           0            0             1           0            1
 #[8,] 6           0            1             0           0            0             1           0            1
 #[9,] 0           0            1             0           0            0             1           0            1
 #         excludeyellow
 #[1,]             0
 #[2,]             0
 #[3,]             0
 #[4,]             1
 #[5,]             1
 #[6,]             1
 #[7,]             0
 #[8,]             0
 #[9,]             0
```

If you want to retain the group info you can:

```
 finalmatrix = cbind(m, finalmatrix)
```

But then `finalmatrix` will be character type object.

Comment: Does this account for all variables in both group_1 and group_2? In simplifying, I may have been misleading... but all variables that need to be turned into dummies are not included in each group in my data. Sorry if that was confusing. There may be variables that are in group_1 and not in group_2 (and vice versa), which is why I have been determining which dummy variables to add using a separate process).

Comment: @Luke_ew you can convert the `group_1` ,`group_2` and `exclude` separately and then combine them with the `response`. The model needs to know that what values were present in the corresponding groups and which ones were excluded.

Comment: @Luke_ew If you drop off the grouping variables you will save on the conversion to numeric again step. Your model should look something like: `response ~ group_1yellow + group_1blue + group_1green + group_2green + group_2yellow + group_2blue + excludeyellow + excludeblue + excludegreen`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm just trying to wrap my head around how I would do that. In the actual data, there are 12 groups... I'm in a little over my head here... could you maybe give an example for how I would go about doing that? Maybe I'm not understanding fully.

Comment: @Luke_ew In the data sample that you have provided in the question description,` group_1` and `exclude` have the same values. Is it the case always?

Comment: Oh god dammit... no, that's not the case. Sorry.

Comment: @Luke_ew So in that case you can go with my suggestion of creating a dummy for each of `group_1`, `group_2` and `exclude`. My suggestion would be wrong if that was the case.

Comment: @Luke_ew I have edited my code to incorporate all the three variables in the encoding process.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with that. It may take a while to use this with 12 variables, but I think it will be worth it if I can accomplish this in a matrix. Hopefully I can make it work.

Comment: @Luke_ew you must read about  **one hot encoding**, to get a grasp of the concept.